# special characters is not allow in xml file in asset folder in Android

Tags: android, xml

How to well formed in xml file in Asset folder in Android.org.apache.harmony.xml.ExpatParser$ParseException: At line 19, column 24:not well-formed (invalid token)
at org.apache.harmony.xml.ExpatParser.parseFragment(ExpatParser.java:520)
at org.apache.harmony.xml.ExpatParser.parseDocument(ExpatParser.java:479)

Here is xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<menu>
   <item>
        <QNO>50</QNO>    
        <QUESTIONS>Which declaration of the main method below would allow a class to be started as a standalone program. Select the one correct answer.</QUESTIONS>
        <ANSWER>35,35</ANSWER>
        <OPTIONA>35,35</OPTIONA>
        <OPTIONB>35,40</OPTIONB>
        <OPTIONC>36,32</OPTIONC>
        <OPTIOND>None of these</OPTIOND>
        <EXPLAINATION>NONE</EXPLAINATION>       
        <QUESTIONTYPE>JAVA</QUESTIONTYPE>
    </item>
<item>
        <QNO>49</QNO>    
        <QUESTIONS>What all gets printed when the following code is compiled and run? Select the three correct answers.
 public class xyz {
   public static void main(String args[]) {
      for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
         for(int j = 2; j>= 0; j--) {
            if(i == j) break;
            System.out.println("i=" + i + " j="+j);
         }
      }
   }
}</QUESTIONS>
        <ANSWER>35,35</ANSWER>
        <OPTIONA>35,35</OPTIONA>
        <OPTIONB>35,40</OPTIONB>
        <OPTIONC>36,32</OPTIONC>
        <OPTIOND>None of these</OPTIOND>
        <EXPLAINATION>NONE</EXPLAINATION>       
        <QUESTIONTYPE>JAVA</QUESTIONTYPE>
    </item>
<item>
<menu>
```

At line 19, column 24 =public static void main(String args[]) {for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {

Comment: The characters `<` and `&` are strictly illegal in the content of XML, furthermore it's a good habit replace this two and also the follow: `&lt;` = `<`, `&gt;` = `>`, `&amp;` = `&`, `&apos;` = `'`, `&quot;`=`"`.

Answer (score 1):

The code snippet contains `<` which is also the XML metacharacter for starting a tag.

Either replace `<` with `&lt;` or wrap the code in unparsed CDATA block:

```
<![CDATA[ ... ]]>
```

Comment: :Thanks for the reply.Can you tell me how and where is to used  this tag in the above xml file.

Comment: I used your code line but my tag is not show on the screen.

Comment: :like this   <![CDATA[<QUESTIONS>What all gets printed when the following code is compiled and run? Select the three correct answers.
 public class xyz {
   public static void main(String args[]) {
      for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
         for(int j = 2; j>= 0; j--) {
            if(i == j) break;
            System.out.println("i=" + i + " j="+j);
         }
      }
   }
}</QUESTIONS>]]>

Answer (score -1):

```
 i=0 j=2
 i=0 j=1
 i=1 j=2
```

;-).

Comment: You are not understand my question or post.I'm saying how to write <QUESTIONS>What all gets printed when the following code is compiled and run? Select the three correct answers.
 public class xyz {
   public static void main(String args[]) {
      for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
         for(int j = 2; j>= 0; j--) {
            if(i == j) break;
            System.out.println("i=" + i + " j="+j);
         }
      }
   }
}</QUESTIONS> this tag in xml in well formate with special characters.I don't want output.

Comment: nice joke, but not an answer.